# Cursor moving erratically (C)

Tags: c, termios

I'm having some trouble doing a Nim game program. So far I have a program that will show a pyramid of pipes. It looks like the "start position" pyramid on this picture.

http://www.mathsisfun.com/puzzles/images/b-nim.gif

Anyways, I'm having trouble moving around this, whenever I try moving around, my cursor will move in completely erratic ways. Thid will make the game totally unplayable. I'm not sure if it is a problem with my counting variables or even some smaller thing I'm totally missing, anyways here's what I have:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int     nim()
   {
     char   *tab;

     if ((tab = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20 + 4)) == NULL)
       return (-1);
     tab = "   |   \n  |||   \n ||||| \n |||||||\n"; /* this is indeed a nasty way to do it :P */
     putstr(tab);
   }

   int     move_normally()
   {
     char  bffr[10];
     int   x;
     int   y;

     x = 0;
     y = 0;
     while (42 && x <= 6 && y <= 3)
       {
         read(0, bffr, 10);
         putstr(tgoto(tgetstr("cm", NULL), x, y);
         if (bffr[2] == 66 && y <= 3 && x <= 6)
           y++
         else if (bffr[2] == 65 && x <= 6 && y <= 3 && (y - 1) >= 0)
           y = y - 1;
         else if (bffr[2] == 67 && x <= 6 && y <= 3)
           x++
         else if (bffr[2] == 68 && x <= 6 && y <= 3 && (x - 1) >= 0)
           x++
       } 
   }
```

So, is there something I'm missing here? everything else works almost perfectly and I can't get my hands on why this is giving trouble. Also, are there any other ways to do this? I'm open to any alternative way.

Comment: You allocate memory for the string in `nim` but then you overwrite the pointer with a string literal and loose the allocated memory. Even when using [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) instead you have a memory leak.

Comment: Btw, *this* code does not compile ... which makes me wonder what else you omitted.

Comment: Also, I'm using ncurses to make this work, I'll check if I didn't forget anything, I'll edit it if I find why it doesn't compile.